# Returning to rails after time spent away. Syntax confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

It's a really simple question. Is this:

```
format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

100% equivalent to this:

```
format.json { render json: @student.errors, status => :unprocessable_entity }
```

It seems to be, but maybe I'm missing a subtlety? If it is equivalent, why is the colon notation better? I assume there's a reason, as Rails uses the first notation in scaffolds, but those opposing colons bother me.

Comment: The colon notation was introduced in Ruby 1.9 and looks a lot cleaner. But I don't see arrow notation as being deprecated any time soon or having any advantages in this particular case, so yea I think its more about what you prefer using.

Comment: According to the duplicated answer, there are some differences. The TL;DR version being that `=>` will always work as expected and `:` will not. Also, the `=>` is called a "rocket," which is great.

Comment: @crowhill How doesn't it work as expected? The semantics are well-defined. Are you referring to how it expects the value to be a valid symbol?